# XML Schema can I use unique when using ref?

Tags: xml, xsd, unique-constraint

Visual Studio gave me an error I can't see is really against the XML schema definition.

When I have a unique constraint on a collection which element I Ref to it says

```
When the ref attribute is present, the type attribute and complexType, simpleType, key, keyref, and unique elements cannot be present.
```

Is this correct and if so am I forced to declare the child element within it's parent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  targetNamespace="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="titletype">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Warlord"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="FirstMate"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Jester"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="warlord">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="warlordName" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="title" type="titletype" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="warband">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warbandName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="warlords">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="warlord" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:unique name="eachTitleOnlyOnce">
                        <xs:selector xpath="warlord"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@title"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Am I using the Unique correct?

**EDIT**

What about this:

```
<xs:complexType  name="warlordtype">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="title" type="titletype" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="warband">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warbandName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="warlords">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="warlord" type="warlordtype" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:unique name="eachTitleOnlyOnce">
                        <xs:selector xpath="warlord"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@title"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique element can't be in ref element. Check [element definition.](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp)

Can you use this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="titletype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Warlord"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="FirstMate"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Jester"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="warlord">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warlordName" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="titletype"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="eachTitleOnlyOnce">
        <xs:selector xpath="warlord"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@title"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="warband">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warbandName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="warlords">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="warlord" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I don't know, can I :P
So I could declare the unique inside the element. What if I would use the element in more then one place and would only wan't the unique in one of those collections?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible in XSD. You can [reuse type](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11057/XSD-Using-the-include-element-for-schematic-reuse) type but not unique. Also parent element for [unique](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_unique.asp) can be only "element".

Comment: What if I make warlord as a type, why wouldn't the unique work, how could I make it work?

Comment: You can define type for complexType, simpleType, etc. And unique should be in element definition but in type definition.

Comment: You can see in my edit in the original question, The type doesn't have a element. Anyway to this better?

Answer (score 1):

A unique constraint for a certain element must always appear in the containing element. 
What you probably want to express is something like this: "The children of a **warlords** element (these children are warlord elements) must have a unique title"
If you change your xsd as below, it should work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  targetNamespace="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://mysticwarlords.kaa/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="titletype">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Warlord"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="FirstMate"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Jester"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="warlord">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="warlordName" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="title" type="titletype" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="warband">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="warbandName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="warlords">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="warlord" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="eachTitleOnlyOnce">
                        <xs:selector xpath="warlord"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@title"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```